# Syntax Error in SQL Query-Ms Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have the following SQl query in VBA and it gives me a syntax error when I run the form. I tried writing the query again, but I ended up with the same error. Any help would be appreciated.Thank you:

```
 Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT & _
          Purchases.SupplierLocation & _
        , Purchases.MinWeight & _
        , Purchases.MaxWeight & _
        , Purchases.PortofDischarge & _
        , Purchases.PlaceofDelivery & _
        , Purchases.PriceTermsLocation " & _

         "FROM ( & _
          Vendors & _
          RIGHT JOIN Purchases & _
             ON Vendors.VendorID=Purchases.VendorID & _
          ) & _
          INNER JOIN & _
              (SELECT Max(PODate) as MaxPODate & _
               FROM Purchases & _
               WHERE Purchases.VendorID = '" & Nz(Me.VendorID, "") & "' & _
               AND Purchases.Grade = '" & Nz(Me.Grade, "") & "' & _
               AND Purchases.PurchaseID <> " & Nz(Me.PurchaseID, 0) & " & _
              ) RecentPurchase & _
             ON Purchases.PODate = RecentPurchase.MaxPODate " & _
         "WHERE Purchases.VendorID = '" & Nz(Me.VendorID, "") & "' & _
          AND Purchases.Grade = '" & Nz(Me.Grade, "") & "' & _
          AND Purchases.PurchaseID <> '" & Nz(Me.PurchaseID, 0)"' & _
         "ORDER BY Min(IIf(Vendors.VendorID=Purchases.VendorID,1,2))")
```

Comment: I hope this isn't too rude, but you would probably be able to easily troubleshoot your code if it was well-formatted... it certainly couldn't hurt at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed a lot of double quotes:

```
Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT " & _
              "Purchases.SupplierLocation " & _
            ", Purchases.MinWeight " & _
            ", Purchases.MaxWeight " & _
            ", Purchases.PortofDischarge " & _
            ", Purchases.PlaceofDelivery " & _
            ", Purchases.PriceTermsLocation " & _
             "FROM ( " & _
              "Vendors " & _
              "RIGHT JOIN Purchases " & _
               "  ON Vendors.VendorID=Purchases.VendorID " & _
              ") " & _
              "INNER JOIN " & _
                  "(SELECT Max(PODate) as MaxPODate " & _
                  " FROM Purchases " & _
                  " WHERE Purchases.VendorID = '" & Nz(Me.VendorID, "") & "' " & _
                  " AND Purchases.Grade = '" & Nz(Me.Grade, "") & "' " & _
                  " AND Purchases.PurchaseID <> " & Nz(Me.PurchaseID, 0) & _
                 " ) RecentPurchase " & _
                " ON Purchases.PODate = RecentPurchase.MaxPODate " & _
             "WHERE Purchases.VendorID = '" & Nz(Me.VendorID, "") & "' " & _
             " AND Purchases.Grade = '" & Nz(Me.Grade, "") & "' " & _
             " AND Purchases.PurchaseID <> '" & Nz(Me.PurchaseID, 0) & "' " & _
             "ORDER BY Min(IIf(Vendors.VendorID=Purchases.VendorID,1,2))")
```

Answer (score 1):

As @JacobH stated it could be clearer but it could be that just before the order by :

```
"' & _ "ORDER BY
```

should be

```
"'" & _ "ORDER BY
```

Comment: Good spotting, you have better eyes than I do!

Comment: Tried it. It is still giving me the same syntax error.